# cargo build-bpf no such command: `+solana` running build:program-rust

Tags: solana-program, cargo

Ran the code npm run build:program-rust getting this error
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling rustup and also solana tool chain still nothing

> helloworld@0.0.1 build:program-rust
> cargo build-bpf --manifest-path=./src/program-rust/Cargo.toml --bpf-out-dir=dist/program

info: uninstalling toolchain 'solana'
info: toolchain 'solana' uninstalled
error: no such command: `+solana`

```
    Cargo does not handle `+toolchain` directives.
    Did you mean to invoke `cargo` through `rustup` instead?
```

Answer (score 1):

This could come from a couple of sources:

- Rust is old: be sure to upgrade with `rustup update stable`
- the Solana toolsuite isn't installed: be sure to install it https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools
- the Solana toolsuite is old: be sure to upgrade with `solana-install init 1.17.13` (as of this writing)

Answer (score 0):

This error has to do with a deprecated version where as before it would use cargo build - bpf but got deprecated wich probably means ur anchor cli its also deprecated.

Btw why are you calling this :npm run build:program-rust ??

if you are building in native rust its cargo build if you are using anchor should be anchor build

Comment: Some people do use native to build Solana instead of Anchor. It seems their main CLI was outdated as per Jon's answer